# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable Opwn CV

Tags: python, list

I am making a bloodcell tracker with open cv, and in one of the lines, it gave me the "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" error. Can you help me?
(I already know there is a similar question, but it does not seem to help me)

```
final_contours = []
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if 10000 >= area >= 360:
        final_contours.append(contour)            
for cell_id, value in final_contours():
    cv2.circle(frame, (int(value[0]), int(value[1])), int(50), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

Comment: You are calling an array like a function in your loop.

Comment: Please re-read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. When you get an error message, the first thing you should do is try to *read* and *understand* the error message. For example, what line of code is it telling you has the problem? What kind of error is it? Does the error message make sense to you? What thing appears to be the list, and why is it being "called"?

Comment: "I already know there is a similar question, but it does not seem to help me" When this happens, you should show us the question you are talking about, explain (if applicable) what specific thing you tried changing in the code after reading it, and explain *why* it did not help.

Comment: Hint: where your code says `for cell_id, value in final_contours():`, what do you think the `()` part means? Should it be in your code? Why or why not?

Comment: You should look at how callables get passed arguments in parentheses `()`  to provide them (mostly input) values for execution and how indexables are indexed using brackets `[]` to access their contents.